# Relation between integrals and functions inequalities

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, inequality, definite-integrals

Given f is defined to $x \in [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $$\int_0^1f^2dx<\frac13<\int_0^1xf(x)dx$$ Find all functions that satisifies all of this conditions.

My fisrt try was to see $\frac13 = \int_0^1x^2dx$ so my doubt is if I can do this:
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx<\int_a^b g(x)dx \implies f(x) < g(x)$$ for some x in (a,b).
Doing this, I find f(x) < x and f(x) > x for some x in (0,1), so no one function f satisifies this given conditions.

Is this correct?

Comment: You've eliminated one function, $f(x)=x$. Unfortunately that's insufficient to rule out all possible functions.

Comment: Take $h(x)  = f(x ) - x$   for $0 \geq x \leq 1,$   and note $h^2 \geq 0$   so that $ \int_0^1 h^2  dx \geq 0.$  Combine that with the conditions about $1/3,$  what happens?

Comment: they probably intended $\int_0^1f^2dx \leq \frac13 \leq \int_0^1xf(x)dx$

Comment: you should specify in what class you are studying the problem (i.e., Riemann integrable functions, continuous functions, some $L^p$ space, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, suppose you have such a function, then you have from CS inequality
$$\int_0^1f^2 dx = 3\int_0^1 x^2 dx \; \int_0^1f^2dx \geqslant 3\left( \int_0^1xf(x) dx\right)^2 > \frac13$$
which contradicts one of the conditions...